# How to call "Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup"?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, powershell-cmdlet

There is a PowerShell [cmdlet `Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/invoke-mgsubscribegroup?view=graph-powershell-beta) that I want to call this way:

```
Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup -GroupId da2d17a7-64a5-43e5-9d95-7b70333dd78c 
                        @{ UserId = "ed3d927d-7999-459f-955d-2afc272bd4d4" }
```

(Split into multiple lines for better readability)

When calling it, I get en error message:

> A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "System.Collections.Hashtable".

Since I'm not *that* deep into PowerShell I must have some false understanding of how to pass a hashtable, or I have misunderstood [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/invoke-mgsubscribegroup?view=graph-powershell-beta#notes) that says:

> ...To create the parameters described below, construct a hash table containing the appropriate properties...

#### My question

What is the correct syntax to call the `Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup` cmdlet and pass the user ID?

Comment: Is splatting what you're after? `$MyVar = @{ GroupId = 'da2d17a7-64a5-43e5-9d95-7b70333dd78c' }; Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup @MyVar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69330624/45375):

PowerShell's [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax) - available locally via `Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup -?` or `Get-Command -Syntax Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup` - contain all the relevant information.

That said, they're not easy to read, especially locally, and there's room for future improvement.

Quoting from [`Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup`'s documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.groups/invoke-mgsubscribegroup):

```sh
Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup
      -GroupId <String>
      # ...
```

```sh
Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup
      -InputObject <IGroupsIdentity>
      # ...
```

- Each (partial) quote represents a distinct [parameter set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parameter_Sets), i.e. a unique combination of parameters representing a distinct feature group.
- That `-GroupId` and `-InputObject` are in *different* parameter sets and are *exclusive* to each, tells you that you cannot use them *both* in a given invocation (they way you mistakenly tried), i.e., that they are *mutually exclusive*.
- Additionally, given that the parameter *names* `-GroupId` and `-InputObject` are *not* enclosed in `[...]` means that you can only pass *named*, not *positional* arguments to them - that is, you must precede an argument to bind to these parameters *with the parameter name*; e.g, `-GroupId foo` rather than just `foo`.
- By convention, a parameter named `-InputObject` is typically used to represent values that can be supplied *via the pipeline*, as evidenced by the parameter's description stating `Accept pipeline input:    True` - locally, you can see this with either `Get-Help -Full  Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup` or - parameter-specifically - with `Get-Help Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup -Parameter InputObject`

  - Often, *multiple* input objects can *only* (meaningfully) be supplied via the pipeline; that is, `-InputObject` is often a mere *implementation detail* whose purpose is to facilitate *pipeline input* - see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).
  - [GitHub issue #4135](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4135) proposes making syntax diagrams *directly* reflect which parameters accept pipeline input.

What complicates matters with respect to `Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup`'s documentation, specifically (which seems to be very sparse in general):

- The help topic contains *no examples* (which you could normally request locally with `Get-Help -Examples Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup`)
- The data type of the `-InputObject` parameter, `<IGroupsIdentity>` (`Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.IGroupsIdentity`) doesn't seem to have its own documentation; it is only described in the "Notes" section of the help topic, as accepting a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`), along with a list of the supported entries (keys and value types).

All that said: you could have passed your hashtable *via the pipeline*, as follows:

```sh
@{ 
  UserId = 'ed3d927d-7999-459f-955d-2afc272bd4d4'
  GroupId = 'da2d17a7-64a5-43e5-9d95-7b70333dd78c'
} | Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup
```

The advantage of this approach over passing an *argument* to `-InputObject` is that it would allow you to pass *multiple* hashtables to act on.

Answer (score 2):

After further investigating and reading the documentation again and again, I've found the correct syntax:

```
Invoke-MgSubscribeGroup -InputObject @{ 
    UserId = "ed3d927d-7999-459f-955d-2afc272bd4d4"; 
    GroupId = "da2d17a7-64a5-43e5-9d95-7b70333dd78c" }
```

(Split into multiple lines for better readability)

I now face permission issues, but this is out-of-scope for this question, since I've asked for the correct syntax only.